# Remove warning "Tab has been converted to Blank Space."

Tags: pgfplots, charts, filecontents

I get this warning "Tab has been converted to Blank Space." how can I remove it, and why do I get it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Gjør det mulig å bruke norske bokstaver
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontenc 
    \usepackage{graphicx}                           % Grafisk pakke
    \usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}               % For å sette marginer
    \usepackage{float}                              % Plassering av tab/fig
    \usepackage{url}                                % Håntering av URL:er
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                   % Removes indent (works the same as \noindent )
    \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}                  % Brukes til a forandre mellomrom rundt overskrifter
    \usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} % Bibliography
    \usepackage{textcomp}                           % Brukes for å fjerne advarsler fra gensymb
    \usepackage{gensymb}                            % Adds symbols, as degree sign, etc.
    \usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}                  % Setter inn innholdsfortengelse i innholdsfortengelse + nr. på referanser
    \usepackage{afterpage}                          % For nye komandoer
    \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}               % For tabeller
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[norsk]{babel}                       % Brukes i oversetning
    \usepackage{booktabs}                           % Brukes på tabeller
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}                 % Viser dato \today i ISO format
    %\usepackage{pdflscape}                          % For landscape modus for enkelt sider, spesefik for compiler
    \usepackage{adjustbox}                          % For tables
    \usepackage{csquotes}                           % ??? noe med \cite
    \usepackage{amsmath}                            % TIl \text for matte
    \usepackage{subcaption}                         % to bilder vedsiden av hverandre
    \usepackage{pgfplots}                           % Grafer
        \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{filecontents}                       % Filer inni filer
    \usepackage{enumitem}                           % Numerering med bokstaver osv
    \usepackage{silence}                            % Mute warnings
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}                % Ha etter alle andre pakker

\begin{document}

    \begin{filecontents}{poissons.txt}
    57.53   -0.8191
    60.49   -0.7514
    63.64   -0.6641
    66.96   -0.5524
    70.46   -0.4229
    74.12   -0.2858
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{stress.txt}
    57.53   1294.740473
    60.49   1331.223722
    63.64   1369.365567
    66.96   1221.925859
    70.46   1303.400342
    74.12   1386.914646
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                width=0.88\linewidth,
                height=6cm,
                xlabel={$\theta$},
                ylabel={$\nu$},
                ytick distance=0.1,
                xtick distance=5,
                ]
                \addplot+[smooth, mark=*] table{poissons.txt};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Poissons ratio mot vinkel}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    width=0.88\linewidth,
                    height=6cm,
                    xlabel={$\theta$},
                    ylabel={$\sigma$},
                    ytick distance=50,
                    xtick distance=5,
                ]
                \addplot+[smooth, mark=*] table{stress.txt};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Stress ratio mot vinkel}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{a viser bla.}
        \label{fig:M1grafeVinkel}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \usepackage` please fix it so that it produces the eroror you ask about, and also remove any packages not needed for the example, to make it easier to debug

Comment: with the edited example I get no warning about tabs.  Did you have tabs in your original document (they get converted to spaces in code sections in this site) you should do teh same in your files and the warning will go

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, but why does it mather that I have tab instead of space?

Comment: because (as it says in the message) tabs are converted to spaces so alignment is lost (as it always converts a tab to the same number of spaces, it doesn't track how many characters are on the line before the tab. tabs in text files are evil:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the help, it was something with excel tabs that made the warning. Tabs everwhere else was fine, but the one copied from excel made the error for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle said it was simple, I had tab some places and that was a problem for some reason. The tables was copied from Excel, and when I removed the tab and replaced it with a space the warning disappeared. But tabs everywhere else worked fine for some reason, so the tables copied from excel must have had something strange in them.

Comment: tabs in normal text work like spaces (with no warning) in TeX, but filecontents catches them and warns in case you were writing a text file where the alignment mattered and treating tabs as spaces is not good. Also if you use the current 2018-04-01 LaTeX release you get no warning at all (but that's a bug and I'll fix)

Comment: I used v2.overleaf.com if that mathers @DavidCarlisle.